# Align icon horizontally to stacked circle with Font Awesome

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, font-awesome

My website template uses:

- Foundation 6: Zurb Template
- Font Awesome 4.7

The following gives me an envelope icon stacked on an inversed circle which basically is working fine.

```
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-2x fa-inverse"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x"></i>
  </span>
```

However the envelope icon is not centered (aligned vertically) in the circle. Using the browser's dev tools it seems as if the envelope is centered in the surrounding `<i>` element.

How can I center the icon in the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overrule the `display` property for `fa-stack`. `flexbox` will allow you to center both icons in the `span`, horizontally and vertically.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.fa-stack {
  display: inline-flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-2x fa-inverse"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x"></i>
  </span>
```